# Couldn't understand Enum Flags with 0x2 values

Tags: c#, enums, enum-flags

I am trying to understand a portion of code but couldn't understand it so far ...

```
[Flags]
public enum Products
{
  Pepsi = 0x1,
  Coca = 0x2,
  Miranda = 0x3,
  Dew = 0x4,
  Wine = 0x5 
} 


Products pp = (Products)12;
pp.HasFlag(Products.Dew); ==> True
pp.HasFlag(Products.Miranda); ==> False
pp.HasFlag(Products.Coca); ==> False
```

I want to know why `pp.HasFlag(Products.Dew)` is `True` and `pp.HasFlag(Products.Miranda)` is `False` . I thought it is working as 0x1 = 1, 0x2 = 2, 0x3 = 4, 0x4 = 8, 0x5 = 16. Kindly guide me what is going on

Comment: I don't really see a reason to downvote this question. At least not whithout stating a reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial declaration equals to

```
[Flags]
public enum Products
{
  Pepsi = 0x1,
  Coca = 0x2,
  Miranda = Coca | Pepsi, // equals to 0x3 since 0x3 == 0x2 | 0x1
  Dew = 0x4,
  Wine = Dew | Pepsi      // equals to 0x5 since 0x5 == 0x4 | 0x1
}
```

You probably want

```
[Flags]
public enum Products
{
  Pepsi = 0x1,
  Coca = 0x2,
  Miranda = 0x4,
  Dew = 0x8,
  Wine = 0x10
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're mistaken about `0x` means. `0x5` does not equal 16, it equals 5. `0x` lets you write hexadecimal, so that you could write `0xA` = 10.

Change your definition to be:

```
public enum Products
{
    Pepsi = 1,
    Coca = 2,
    Miranda = 4,
    Dew = 8,
    Wine = 16 
}
```

Thus, `12` would represent the flag `Dew` and `Miranda`

Comment: HasFlag(Products.Dew) is True ?

Comment: @WaqarAhmed Yes, because `12` represents `8+4` (which is Dew and Miranda).

Comment: According to my code Why pp.HasFlag(Products.Dew) is True and pp.HasFlag(Products.Miranda) is False?

Comment: @WaqarAhmed Because `12` is `1100` in binary. `Miranda (3)` is `0011`. `Dew (4)` is `0100`. `0100 & 1100` yields `0100`, so the flag is *on* for Dew. `0011 & 1100` yields `0000`, so the flag is *off* for miranda.

Answer (score 1):

You should read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c?rq=1).
Your flags are little bit incorrect. For example:

```
Pepsi | Cola = Miranda
 0001 | 0010 = 0011
```

Logically right flags:

```
[Flags]
public enum Products
{
  Pepsi = 0x1,
  Coca = 0x2,
  Miranda = 0x4,
  Dew = 0x8,
  Wine = 0x0A 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand `Flags` it's better to convert each flag value to its binary representation. So in your case we have:

```
[Flags]
public enum Products
{
  Pepsi = 0x1, //--> 0001
  Coca = 0x2, //--> 0010
  Miranda = 0x3, //--> 0011
  Dew = 0x4, //--> 0100
  Wine = 0x5 // --> 0101
}
```

then when 12 (which in binary is '1100') casted to `Products` enum you can clearly see that the flag bit for Dew (which is 0100) is on (or 1 in binary). In other words, every product which its third bit from right is 1 has Dew in it.